# error in shiny: asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE)

Tags: shiny-server, jsonlite

Jsonlite error, i do not understand what is triggering this error.

I wanted to build an app in shiny, visualising rainfall data. The dataset was in wide form, and that for some reason was not working, so i converted it to long form, after which it started showing jsonlite error: Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. Here is the code, i have omitted unncessary parts.Sorry for not giving reprex.

ui<-fluidpage(selectInput("area","Select an area of choice", choices =names(file)
, selected = NULL))

server<-function(input, output){
filter.area<- reactive( select(file, input$area, Time)
)

output$timeseries<- renderPlot({

```
  melt.area<- melt(filter.area(), id.vars="Time", variable.name="region", value.name = "rainfall")

  ggplot(melt.area)  + geom_line(aes(x=Time, y=rainfall), color= "blue")
```

})
}
Created on 2023-05-29 with reprex v2.0.2